# In VBA I have code for pasting a button from one worksheet to another (using range) and I get an error: Named argument not found

Tags: excel, vba

I want to avoid using .select and .activate as they has given me problems in the past. The error is given in the second to last line at "Format:"

error: Named argument not found

```
Dim rngOpenButtonTo As Range
Set rngOpenButtonTo = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Biofuel LDPV").Range("I10")

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("LDPV").Shapes("Button 10").Copy

rngOpenButtonTo.PasteSpecial Format:="Microsoft Office Drawing Object", _
                    Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following Code:

```vb
Dim rngOpenButtonTo As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Biofuel LDPV")
Set rngOpenButtonTo = ws.Range("I10")

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("LDPV").Shapes("Button 10").Copy

ws.Paste Destination:=rngOpenButtonTo
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 different `PasteSpecial`-routines in VBA for Excel, and you have mixed them up.
The first one is [`Range.PasteSpecial`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.pastespecial), this is to copy worksheet data (data that is stored within cells and can be accessed via `Range`-variable).

The second is [`Worksheet.PasteSpecial`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Worksheet.PasteSpecial) - this is to copy anything else, either data from a different application, or to copy a shape from Excel and maybe convert it. The drawback of this method is that it doesn't have a parameter to tell where you want the content to be copied to, it always uses the current selected cell, so either you use a `Select`-statement or you add some extra logic to fetch the shape that was added (it's the last member in the `shape`-collection) and place it where ever you want by changing it's `Left`- and `Top`-properties.

So to copy a shape, you need to use the Worksheet variant, but you call the Range-Method, and that doesn't have a `Format`-parameter (as it copied only Excel data) - thus the error you face.

As you only want to copy a Shape, there is no need to use `PasteSpecial` (the worksheet version), you can simply use `Paste`, however, this method exists only for a Worksheet, not for a Range, but is has a parameter `Destination` to specify where you want to place the content. The answer of **MGP** shows exactly how to use this, so no need to repeat it here.